# Wordpress block development: Save-function parameters are empty when reloading the page

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, wordpress-plugin-creation

im developing a plugin for a block type called "tab-menu". I got it working so far but I have issues saving the template. When I create a post, put my block type in there, do some changes, save and reload the page, I get an error saying something like

```
Error validating block type:
The save method generated the output: <div class="tab"></div>

The content was expected to be: <div class="tab"><button class="tablinks">tab-1</button><button class="tablinks">tab-2</button></div>
```

More of the story:

My idea is that the block consists of a parent which is responsible for displaying the tab menu and the InnerBlocks (the children). The children also have an InnerBlock, so the user can put into the content of a tab whatever he/she wants.
The children "tab-menu-items" have an attribute "tabName" which is used to display the name in the tab menu for that tab item. To do so, I grab all children and create a tab for each one (whenever a tab menu item is added, selected, renamed, etc).

```
var tabContainer = document.querySelector('.tab');
// ...
const childBlocks = wp.data.select('core/block-editor').getBlocks(clientId);
childBlocks.forEach((childBlock, idx) => {
  childBlock.innerBlocks?.forEach(ib => {
    const childAttributes = ib.attributes;
    console.log("CHILD ATTRIBUTES", childAttributes)

    const tabLink = document.createElement('button');
    tabLink.className = 'tablinks';
    tabLink.textContent = childAttributes.tabName;
    tabLink.addEventListener('click', (evt) => {
      this.openTag(evt, tabLink.textContent || tabLink.innerText, idx);
    });
    tabContainer.appendChild(tabLink);
  });
});
```

The attribute is defined at the child level as said

```
registerBlockType( metadata.name, {
    attributes: {
        tabName: {
            type: 'string',
            default: 'example-1',
        },
    },
    /**
     * @see ./edit.js
     */
    edit: Edit,

    /**
     * @see ./save.js
     */
    save,
} );
```

The save function of the parent looks like this

```
export default function save(props) {
    console.log("save::props", props);
    const tab = new Tab();

    return (
        <div class="tabcontrol">
            <div class="tab">
                {Array.isArray(props.innerBlocks) && props.innerBlocks.map((innerBlock, i) => {
                    console.log("save::Really rendering the innerblocks of the props");
                    return (<button key={i} class="tablinks" onClick={(event) => tab.openTag(event, innerBlock.attributes.tabName, i)}>{innerBlock.attributes.tabName}</button>)
                })}
            </div>

            <InnerBlocks.Content />
        </div>
    );
}
```

The `props` parameter of the save method has the properties `attributes` and `innerBlocks`. When I add this block to the editor and work with it, it works fine, even when I update the post. However, when I refresh the page, the `props` parameter do not have the properties `attributes` and `innerBlocks` anymore. Therefore, no buttons are printed.

What do I need to do here? Do I need to save the `props` somehow?

Here is also the edit function of the child

```
export default function Edit(props) {
    const { attributes, setAttributes } = props;
    const {
        tabName
    } = attributes;


    function onChangeTabName(newName) {
        setAttributes({ tabName: newName });
    }


    return (
        <div class="tabcontent">
            <InnerBlocks
                template={[
                ]}
            >
            </InnerBlocks>

            <div class="">
                <span>Add content</span>
                <InnerBlocks.ButtonBlockAppender />

            </div>

            <InspectorControls>
                <PanelBody title={__('Settings')}>
                    <TextControl
                        label="Tab name"
                        help="Enter display name for the menu"
                        value={tabName}
                        onChange={(newValue) => {
                            onChangeTabName(newValue);
                        }}
                    />
                </PanelBody>
            </InspectorControls>
        </div>
    );
}
```

as well as the save function of the child

```
export default function save(props) {
    return (
        <div class="tabcontent">
            <InnerBlocks.Content />
        </div>
    );
}
```

and the html structure of the parent

```
return (

        <div class="tabcontrol">
            <div class="tab" >
            </div>

            {children}

            {child_values.map(({ clientId, tabName }, index) => (
                <p id={clientId} key={index}>{tabName}</p>
            ))}
            <div >
                <span>Add tab</span>
                <div class="innerblocks-div-wrapper" onClick={(event) => {
                    tab.createTabs(props.clientId);
                }}>
                    <InnerBlocks.ButtonBlockAppender />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
```

I did research about this phenomal but wasn't finding information that could help me solve the issue. In general it seems to be tricky to have multiple InnerBlocks and example are rare unfortunately.
I was expecting that the props were saved and would be available when refreshing the page.